# Underline single letter in an input placeholder

Tags: css, placeholder, underline

One can apply CSS styling to a placeholder, such as for Firefox:

```
::-moz-placeholder { text-decoration: underline; }
```

However, what I would like to do is underline a single letter in a placeholder, for the purpose of hinting at a hotkey for the user to press (similar to Windows in file menus), such as making the `F`  in `First Name` underlined below:

```
<input type='text' placeholder='First Name' />
```

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: You seem to be using the `placeholder` attribute instead of a label, as opposite to using it just to give an additional hint. The HTML5 specification rather strongly warns against that. So make sure you are solving the right problem.

Comment: Tracking. I am trying to make clean what begs to be complex, which is a series of inputs that demand a previous value displayed below and validation errors displayed above, for entering data against existing data. To add a label field in addition to that when I can use placeholders would just be a waste.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you can achieve this with CSS only in google chrome. For example:

You can select the first letter of placeholder

```
::-webkit-input-placeholder::first-letter {
  color: red;
  text-decoration:underline; 
}
```

**Result:**

[image]

The text-decoration does not render when set with :first-letter in Chrome (Version 39.0.2171.71). So we can achieve the underline with **border-bottom**.

```
::-webkit-input-placeholder::first-letter {
  color: red;
  border-bottom: 1px solid red;
}
```

**Result:**

[image]

**UPDATE:** text-decoration works fine on Chrome 41.0.2235.0 Canary.

[image]

Here is the DEMO: http://codepen.io/MizR/pen/myeJZe

Unfortunately, this solution doesn't work on Firefox. :(

**Update 2:** No longer works. :(

Comment: Whatever browsers do with styling placeholders is not a bug, since no specification says that you should be able to apply CSS to them at all or what limitations there might be.

Comment: This doesn't appear to be working in any current browsers anymore. Failing in Chome (52.0.2743.116 m) and IE 11.

Comment: Yes it is not working! failing to render in new updated browser.

Comment: @MizanurRahman is this possible to make same changes in updated browser. Whats the way get the same in new browser.

Comment: @AnupamMaurya I didn't try any new workaround. I'm not sure about any new solution. I will look into it. :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use an absolute-positioned `u` tag, being careful to use the same font and padding as the `input`.

You'll need to hide the `u` when the `input` has content:

```js
document.getElementById('iFirstName').onkeyup= function() {
  var u= document.getElementById('uFirstName');
  u.style.display= this.value>'' ? 'none':'inline';
};
```

```css
u {
  position: absolute;
  font: 10pt verdana;
  padding: 4px;
}

input {
  padding: 3px;
  font: 10pt verdana;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
}
```

```html
<u id="uFirstName">F</u>
<input id="iFirstName" type='text' placeholder='First Name' />
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are comfortable using `contenteditable` instead of input, you can try:

http://jsfiddle.net/lotusgodkk/GCu2D/473/

HTML:

```
<div contenteditable="true" data-ph="First Name">Hello</div>
```

CSS:

```
div {/*For styling div similar to input*/
    width:300px;
    height:24px;
    border:1px solid grey;
}
div[contentEditable=true]:empty:not(:focus):before {
    content:attr(data-ph);
    color:grey;    
}
div::first-letter {
    text-decoration:underline;
}
```

Comment: Means this would not possible in input element?